# PhpSpreadsheet. Подскажите как теперь называется метод stringFromColumnIndex

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

В phpExcel был метод stringFromColumnIndex([$pColumnIndex = 0]) – данный метод позволял определить по номеру столбца его символьное представление, для этого в качестве параметра необходимо передать его номер;
Какой аналог в PhpSpreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
use \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;

// Выведет: Z
var_dump(Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(26));

// Выведет: R
var_dump(Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(18));

// Выведет 2
var_dump(Coordinate::columnIndexFromString('B'));

// Выведет 26
var_dump(Coordinate::columnIndexFromString('Z'));
```

В документации об этом сказано было.